# How can I efficiently run a scala program multiple times?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala program built with sbt and I want to run it multiple times with different arguments from another program (written in rust).

I can call `sbt run [arg]` each time but this is very slow. Usually one would use the sbt shell and call `run [arg]` multiple times, but I don't know if or how that would work from a script. Additionally, I want to retrieve the output of my program, excluding the output of sbt.

I tried to use `sbt package` and `scala program.jar`, but the thing is that I have no such `scala` binary installed and, anyway, I want to use the local scala version that sbt downloaded, not a system-global version. I do not know how to run my `program.jar` using this local scala version.

I also thought about running my scala program as a child process of my rust program, communicating multiple times through stdin and stdout or some other means.

What is a clean and efficient way to run my scala program multiple times, while providing inputs and retrieving outputs?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to use sbt-assembly, which can build a fat jar that includes all the dependencies (including the appropriate Scala runtime and standard library) and that you can run with `java -jar`.

Comment: Depending on your definition of efficient and multiple, consider turning it into a service with a well-defined interface. Piping stdout is fragile. Also, a JVM likes to stay warm instead of repeatedly started cold. What is your definition of clean and efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command `sbt run` is for development purposes only. To run your app you'd need to package it to `jar`.

You could create jar with `sbt package` but created jar won't contain any external dependencies. You'd need to add them manually to classpath. So you'd need to run your jar with `-cp` parameter and specify all `jars` you'd want to use (including your project `jar`) and provide fully qualified name to your main class:

```
java -cp yourprojectname.jar:external.jar:anotherexternal.jar:. your.package.Main <your args>
```

As Travis has written, easier way is to  create a runnable jar which would contain all your dependencies. You can do it easily with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

Just add `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9")` in file `project/assembly.sbt` in your project directory, then run `sbt assembly`. 
In `target/scala_X.X.X` directory will appear file with name `projectname-assembly-X.X.X.jar`, which you can then run with:

```
java -jar projectname-assembly-X.X.X.jar <your args>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another handy `sbt` plugins that allows you to package your application depending on your target platform which is [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)

Here is how you would package it as a universal zip file:

In you `project/plugins.sbt` (create if needed), add

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt"    % "sbt-native-packager"   % "1.3.3")
```

And enable the plugins into your `build.sbt` by adding:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

You can then run the following command:

```sh
sbt universal:packageBin
```

which out put a zip file under `target/universal`.
You can unzip the zip file and run the script under the bin folder:

```
./target/universal/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/hello -- "My arg1" "My arg2
```

Note that the `--` allows to pass argument to your program.
This plugin allows you to create different format depending on your target platform such as deb files, docker images, dmg files etc.
You can read more about sbt-native-packager [here](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html#setup).